# Abstraction of Column Names in DBIx::Class::ResultSet

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I am developing a Catalyst application that uses [`DBIx::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/~abraxxa/DBIx-Class-0.08209/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm) to access a MySQL database.  The application performs data quality checks on a file.  The files are loaded into a table `FileContent`:

```
 FILE_ID LINE_NUMBER FOO BAR BAZ
 -----------------------------------
 1       1           A   99  Blah
 1       2           B   11  Blargh
 1       3           A   4   Sproing
 1       4           B   7   Sproing
 1       5           B   10  Doink
```

Then I have another table, `Format`, that defines the verification actions of each column:

```
 COL_ORDER COL_NAME VALIDATION
 1         FOO      regex:/^[AB]$/
 2         BAR      unique_number
 3         BAZ      regex:/\S/
```

What I want to do is go through `FileContent` line by line for a given file, applying all of the rules in `Format` to each line:

```
my @lines  = $c->model('DB::FileContent')->search({file_id => 1});
my @format = $c->model('DB::Format')->search();

foreach my $line (@lines)
{
    foreach my $column (@format)
    {
        #Get the field matching this column from $line.
        #e.g. for first $column get $line->foo()  
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how best to efficiently get the column from a line that matches the current column in the format.  The normal way of accessing columns is through methods, such as `$line->foo`.  But what do I do when `foo` is a variable?

I don't think I want to do this:

```
eval "$line->${$column->col_name}";
```

I am aware of get_column, but is this efficient for getting a single value from a row?

```
$line->get_column($column->col_name)
```

What is the most efficient way to retrieve a column based on the value from the other table?  I can use either column name or column position.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Importing files into a relational database for validation doesn't make sense to me. Using a web application framework to do that neither. Can you explain some more why you have chosen to use DBIx::Class and Catalyst to solve your problem?

Comment: @abraxxa, a number of different users have to submit data files to a system.  The application will check their files and give a report of the errors so that they can correct the errors. Also it performs some conversions.  If the files are correct it will submit them to a central database.  The files are CSV files which are going to be loaded into a database, so a relational DB seems like a logical choice of storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first putting all validation rules into a hashref (or a hash), and - most importantly - ensure that FileContent items get inflated into a hashrefs via [DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultClass/HashRefInflator.pm). That makes it much more convenient to access the fields within an item when you cycle through them.

Like this:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# get all formats into a hashref
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

my $format = $c->model('DB::Format')->search({}, { order_by => ['COL_ORDER'] } );
my @col_names = $format->get_column('COL_NAME')->all;
# @col_names now contains qw/FOO BAR BAZ/

my $formats;
@{$formats}{@col_names} = $format->get_column('VALIDATION')->all;

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create an iterator over DB::FileContent, and make items inflate to hashrefs 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

my $file_content  = $c->model('DB::FileContent')->search({file_id => 1});
$file_content->result_class('DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator');
# this ensures that every item inflates into a hashref


# this way you can iterate over items, and don't have to put them all into an array 
while (my $hashref = $file_content->next) {
    # put relevant field values into an array
    my @values = @{$hashref}{@col_names};
}
```

Comment: This approach looks like the way to go.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.